# Facebook SDK Integration Issue using AddThis SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, twitter, addthis

I am having a iOS AddThis SDK issue with the facebook functionality, If the user deathorizes the app on Facebook, the AddThis SDK does not properly notify me via the iOS app to handle that disconnect. This leads the app user to get an error in the facebook SDK that is un "trappable" by the developer when they try to go and share again after having disconnected the app.

Is there anyway to have the AddThis SDK pass such a message or SDK state back to the app so we can reauthorize the user to connect their facebook account to the facebook app within the iOS app?